# HTML2PDF unexpected line-breaks within table

Tags: php, html, css, html2pdf

I'm using HTML2PDF to generate a pdf-file out of a HTML string.

Everything nice and easy, till I came to a very wierd bug. There is a pagebreak in the middle of a `td`. Not only does it not take the `css` with him, but the spot on where it decides to break makes no sence. The sentence is shorter than the sentence above it, while the sentence above only takes up 1 row. Which would mean the sentence with a break would be on just on line, instead, it dicides to use 4 lines. This might sound confusing, so here is an example of the `html`.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Some text longer than the text below.</td>
        <th>Apples</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Text shorter than text above</td>
        <th>Bananas</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, the first `td` is longer than the second `td`, so you'd think if the second `td` would need a line break, the first one needs one to. Unfortunately, html2pdf decides the second `td` needs 3 line breaks, while the first has none.

This bugs out the tablerow below it, in which the `th` overlaps the `td` in every row.

I have looked trough the code and I can say for sure: This is the `html`. No page breaks, nothing.

Here is kinda what it would look like if I were to write the output in html.
**This is not the actual html given to the pdf!** This is just the output, written in html.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Some text longer than the text below.</td>
        <th>Apples</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Text shorter <br>than <br>text <br>above</td>
        <th>Bananas</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Notes:

1. This table is on the bottom of my page, so the line breaks causes a very bugged page-break.
2. I have tried using `page-break-inside: avoid;` on every element (even on the same time) but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. Apparantly, thead and tfoot aren't supported within html2pdf. Html2pdf puts a table in a array and didn't count tfoot and thead in it, but did output it.

What he does is this. You have this code:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        header
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Some text longer than the text below.</td>
        <th>Apples</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Text shorter <br>than <br>text <br>above</td>
        <th>Bananas</th>
    </tr>
    <tfoot>
        footer
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

He placed every row in a array, like this:

```
array (
0 => array (
    0 => "thead"
    1 => ""
1 => array (
    0 => "Some text longer than the text below."
    1 => "Apples"
2 => array (
    0 => "Text shorter than text above"
    1 => "Bananas"
3 => array (
    0 => "footer"
    1 => "")
```

Yet, he'd see only 2 rows, so counted 0 and 1. Which ment he'd output array(0) and array(1). After that, he'd find the rest of the table and just post it as if it's nothing more then a string with tags, while in reality it was a tablerow.

I could be wrong with the explanation, this is just how I picked it up.